# Is it bad to prefix all of my framework class names?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, coding-style, conventions

I develop a lot of frameworks for Flash games and applications. I have always prefixed my class names with a random character or two, to avoid conflict with class names that the developer may already have, for example:

```
class LEntity
```

Recently I had a co-worker blast me for poor and "annoying" naming of classes who then proceeded to rename *every* class in the frameworks I've created for people here to use.

I'm having trouble explaining my reasoning thoroughly enough for him to accept what I've done as a good approach.

Is what I've done above actually a bad thing? If not, how can I explain otherwise? If so, why?

---

Comments are asking about namespaces - I know AS3 in this example has what I know to be called a namespace but I'm not sure if this is the same thing or if it can be used as expected.

Comment: Does your language of choice support namespaces?

Comment: kNo kactually kit kis knot ka kbad kidea ka klot kof kframeworks kdo kit. Csometimes Cthe Cprefixes Cmake Tmore Rsense Mthen LPCSTRothers

Comment: By "random character or two", do you mean each class gets assigned a random, different one? If each are prefixed differently, yes, that's very bad form (impossible to simply know the name!). If your language supports namespaces, you should really use that instead. If not, THEN you consider prefixing with characters (many, many frameworks do it... everyone from OSX (NS) to the Linux GUI toolkits, to Windows (not in .Net, but in the C/C++ frameworks).

Comment: @Kitsune All classes in a given framework of course have the *same* prefix.

Comment: From a bit of Googling, it would appear ActionScript supports namespaces, in which case I would suggest using the built-in namespace support instead of emulating it with prefixes. Prefixes are really intended to emulate the functionality provided by namespaces.

Comment: I only know how to use namespaces in combination with properties or methods - can I apply a namespace to an entire class? Is that where this is going?

Comment: namespaces aside, your reasons for naming your classes seem perfectly valid to me.  it's your style.  your co-worker sounds like a douchebag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Actionscript supports namespaces, there is no reason to use prefixes simply to prevent naming clashes.  That's what namespaces are for.

Some people like to use namespaces to significy member variables (ie, underscore prefix, or sometimes m_) and that has some merit, but simply for the sake of name clashing no.

Comment: In AS3 I only know how to use namespaces for making properties or methods of a given class accessible only from classes who use the required namespace (generally to act like `internal` but without the requirement of all files being in the same package).

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding how namespaces work, and how they are used.  Namespaces do not make classes "accessible", this is done with the access keywords (public, private, etc..). namespaces make identifiers *visible*, not *accessible*.  When you do something like `use namespace foo`, this simply combines namespaces so they are in the same scope.  You can still use namespaced functions by specifying the namespace in front of it (`foo::myfunc()`).  This does a similar purpose to adding a character to the front of your class names, but is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't quite understand what <strike>namespaces</strike>packages are in AS3.

An example:

```
//Class1.as
package com.test.someModule { //This is the package/namespace
  public class Class1 {...}
}

//Class2.as
package com.test.otherModule {
  import com.test.someModule.Class1; //Class1 can be used as "Class1" now. Otherwise you would do "com.test.someModule.Class1"
  import com.test.someModule.*; //You can also use the "*" to "import" all classes in that package
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just the package? When I think namespaces in AS3 I think of actually using the namespace keyword: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/01/a_complete_guid.html

Comment: That's apparently what adobe think namespaces are, but it's not what they are generally used for :) (unless I'm utterly mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with your co-worker, your class names are 'annoying'.

In Actionscript 3 we use the package name to define the namespace of a class.  If you're not sure what namespace means, take the wikipedia definition (as of the time of writing):

> "In general, a namespace is a container for a set of identifiers
>   (names), and allows the disambiguation of homonym identifiers residing
>   in different namespaces."

So you will never "conflict with class names" as long as you name your packages correctly.  Most developers use what is called the *reverse domain notation* to name their packages (e.g com.mywebsite.MyGenericNamedClass).  Domain names are unique so it's very unlikely you would clash with another class.

As a rule of thumb the class name should be as descriptive as possible, so some of your class names will be the same as someone else's class.  Take the default Sprite class for instance:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import uk.co.mywebsite.Sprite;
```

if you then initialize an object:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

The compiler would not know which Sprite you want to initialize (is it the flash sprite or your own custom sprite), and it would throw an error.

The solution is simple: because your packages have been named properly, all you need to do is to use the full class name including the package name to initialize your object:

```
var mySprite:uk.co.mywebsite.Sprite = new uk.co.mywebsite.Sprite();
var myOtherSprite:flash.display.Sprite = new flash.display.Sprite();
```

Mind you, you would rarely need to do that.  This is only necessary if you want to use those two classes (the default Sprite and your own Sprite) in the same scope.  Generally, you would only import your own class:

```
/* we are not importing this any more 
  import flash.display.Sprite;*/

//only importing my own class
import uk.co.mywebsite.Sprite;

/* now I can initialize my object without using the full class name, and the compiler knows 
I mean my own Sprite class */
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

Comment: OK, so give me a reason that my approach is annoying in the context of someone using my library having their own `Entity` class, but they also want to extend my `LEntiy` class. `class Entity extends Entity`? I don't think so. Sure, they could simply rename their Entity class. But what happens if they're using *another* library that already has an Entity class? More common than one would expect.

Comment: I didn't mean to upset you, I borrowed the word "annoying" from your colleague simply because prefixing class names in ActionScript 3 is unnecessary and it just doesn't read as nicely.

If you were to have all your classes at the root directory of your project, naming your class simply Entity could be a problem.  However if you organize your classes into packages it would avoid name clashes, like this:
package com.yourdomain
{
  import com.someoneelsesdomain.Entity;
 
  public class Entity extends com.someoneelsesdomain.Entity
  {
    public function Entity()
    {
      super();
    }
  }
}